# Show that the natural density is $1/2$.

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $$A_b= \left\lbrace{p \in \mathbb{P}| \left(\frac{b}{p}\right)=1 } \right\rbrace $$ and $$  \nu(A_b)=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\#\lbrace {p \in A_b|p\le x}\rbrace}{\pi(x)}$$ the natural density.
For $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ square-free, prove that $$\nu(A_b)=\frac{1}{2}. $$
I do not have really an idea, but I know that $$ \left(\frac{b}{p}\right)$$ is a Dirichlet-character modulo $4|b|$. 
Can someone give me a hint ? Thanks for helping .

Comment: Does quadratic reciprocity help?

Comment: not really , do I have to use the Dirichlet  prime number theorem ?

Comment: Well I was thinking that mod $b$, $p$ is half the time a quadratic residue and half the time not. But then again, I'm not sure how to prove that either. So my next guess is something on $L$ functions ...

Comment: Yes , but I am trying to understand why  $$ \left(\frac{p}{p_{n_j}}\right)  $$ is +1 for 1/2 of nonzero residues mod p_j . I know this is +1 if  p is a quadratic residue mod p_nj .

Comment: @Matillo  the quadratic residues mod $p_{n_j}$ are $1^2,2^2,\dots, (\frac{p_{n_j}-1}{2})^2$.

Comment: @Matillo and because $p$ is uniformly distributed amongst the nonzero residues of $p_{n_j}$

Comment: @mathworker  thanks a lot for your help ! . Yes , partially . I am still thinking about why you split up the legendre symbol . Each has to be 1 and the definition says that then p has to be quadratic residue mod p_nj .

Answer (score 1):

Write $b =p_{n_1}\dots p_{n_k}$ a product of distinct primes. First assume each $p_{n_i}$ is odd. Then for $p \not = p_{n_1},\dots,p_{n_k}$, by quadratic reciprocity, $$(\frac{b}{p}) = (\frac{p_{n_1}}{p})\dots(\frac{p_{n_k}}{p}) = (\frac{p}{p_{n_1}})\dots (\frac{p}{p_{n_k}})(-1)^{\epsilon_p}$$ where $\epsilon_p$ depends (at most) on the residue of $p$ mod $4$. By Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression, $p$ is equidistributed mod $4p_{n_1}\dots p_{n_k}$ and thus, since $(\frac{p}{p_{n_j}})$ is $+1$ for $\frac{1}{2}$ of the nonzero residues mod $p_j$ and $-1$ for the others, we conclude that $(\frac{b}{p})$ is $+1$ half of the time and $-1$ half of the time.

If some $p_{n_j} = 2$... (try to finish this case).